# MongoDB - How to find ONLY embedded documents that have field value that matche a given value

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

This is the structure of a document in my collection where the data is grouped by report week (i.e., all the data for the different currencies released in the same week's report are grouped together)

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": id
    },
    "year": 2024,
    "week": "Report Week 04",
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "Jan 23 2024",
            "reportWeek": "Report Week 04",
            "currencyName": "CANADIAN DOLLAR",
            "marketCode": "090741",
            some more fields...
        },
        some more documents...
    ]
}
```

The `collection.data` field is an embedded array of documents from which I would like to `find` only the documents whose marketCode field value matches a given parameter.

Based off the MongoDB documentation ([Specify a Query Condition on a Field in an Array of Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents)), I came up with this:

```
const dataColl = client.db('database').collection('collection');

    const data = await dataColl.find({

        'data.marketCode': marketCode  // marketCode is a string argument that is passed to the function.

        // I also tried this 'data.marketCode': { $eq: marketCode }

    }).project({projections...}).toArray();
```

I expected that this query will go to all documents in the collection and get every embedded document that has `data.marketCode === marketCode`. However, it just returns the full collection with all the data (albeit with the projections correctly applied).

I need help figuring out the correct `find` command to use.

P.S: `data.marketCode` values are stored as strings in the database

Comment: If you want the `data` to be filtered with `marketCode: marketCode`, you need to filter the data in the projection with `$filter` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the resposne, it was very helpful and I was able to get the desired result.